# CCNode tag - Shows all tags are same

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am new to cocos2d game development.I have subclassed a CCNode,and i am looping to add this subclass to the game layer setting the tag for this node.In the m file of this subclass i am using the touches delegate to detect the element.But the console shows that for any  object of this node created tag's are the same.

Comment: what tag value? If it's -1 you never changed it. If you set it to x in your subclass, all instances of your subclass will have the tag value x (ie the same). Post some code relevant to how you use the tag property.

Answer (score 0):

You must initialise tag for each node. Use uniq integer number as tag. Better use enum.

```
typedef enum
{
    kEnemy_Dog = 1000,
    kEnemy_Cat,
    kEnemy_Rat,
    kEnemy_Bat
}EnemyType;

typedef enum
{
    kHeroType_Lion = 2000,
    kHeroType_Tiger,
    kHeroType_Dino,
    kEnemy_Eagle
}HeroType;


CCSprite *dog = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:TEX_DOG];
dog.tag = kEnemy_Dog;
[self addChild:dog z:2 tag: kEnemy_Dog];


CCSprite *lion = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:TEX_DOG];
lion.tag = kHeroType_Lion;
[self addChild:dog z:2 tag: kHeroType_Lion];

//to check
if(inSprite.tag == kHeroType_Lion)
```